# Get rid of generics in wrapper structs

Tags: rust

I have a data structure with a generic specifying the size of an array:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Data<const X: usize> {
    x: [f64; X],
    y: [f64; X],
}
```

I need these two arrays to have the same length for the struct to make sense.

This data structure is now contained in a container:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Container<const X: usize> { // <-- Should not care about size
    data: Box<Data<X>>,
}
```

This container should not care about the size of the data, so I encapsulated it inside a box, but the generic is still required. The container is wrapped in many other structs, so it seems unfeasible to carry the generic everywhere in the project. But how do I get rid of the generic?

I know that I could introduce a trait like this:

```rust
trait DataTrait: Debug + Clone {}

impl<const X: usize> DataTrait for Data<X> {}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Container {
    data: Box<dyn DataTrait>,
}
```

But this does not seem to work Clone.
<sub>I know there is [this workaround](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/solved-is-it-possible-to-clone-a-boxed-trait-object/1714) or even [dyn-clone](https://github.com/dtolnay/dyn-clone). But adding other derives like `Deserialize` or `Default` is a nightmare I cannot figure out.</sub>

Comment: Why shouldn't the container care about the size of the data? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Regarding to size, alignment, the size doesn't matter, since Data<X> is stored in the heap (Box). So every Container will have the same size and alignment, doesn't matter what X is.

Comment: Since you're involving the heap anyways, why not store 2 `Box<[f64]>` (or a single one of length `2N`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I meant from the functionality side. `Data` has a method which is called from `Container` to retrieve a data point. The `Container`'s functionality does not depend on the `Data`'s size.
But I think I just did get confused how a `Box` works. I think the Box needs to know the size of `Data` for it to work, that is why the generic is necessary.

I am starting to believe using a trait makes to most sense (because I only need one method), but then I have to struggle with object safe traits and use stuff like dyn-clone and erased-serde.

Comment: @cafce25 I need the struct because it is reused in different parts of the project and has a bunch of functionality that I wanted to bundle together in one object for abstraction.

Comment: Yes, and, ...? Why would that prevent the use of `Box<[f64]>` instead of `[f64; N]`?

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to replace `Box<Data<X>>`. Your suggestion would work, yes. And is probably the best solution of the three. But I need both arrays to have the same length. I can write a validation in the constructor, but feels kind of sad to have a type system which can guarantee this kind of stuff and then not use it... Still, that's probably what I will end up doing.

Comment: You could use one array `[(f64, f64)]`

Comment: @TiborVölcker, that's because you want to get rid of the const generic, it is how the compiler provides those checks, without it, those checks **cannot** be performed at compiletime. But the constructor can still have a signature of `new<const N: usize>([f64; N], [f64; N]) -> Data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dynamically sized type (DST) version of your struct in the `Container`:

```rust
#[repr(C)] // `repr(C)` is necessary for the layout guarantees
#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone)]
struct Data<const N: usize>{
    x: [f64; N],
    y: [f64; N],
}

#[repr(transparent)]
struct DynData {
    xy: [f64],
}

impl DynData {
    pub fn x(&self) -> &[f64] {
        &self.xy[..self.xy.len()/2]
    }
    pub fn y(&self) -> &[f64] {
        &self.xy[self.xy.len()/2..]
    }
}

impl<const N: usize> From<Box<Data<N>>> for Box<DynData> {
    fn from(data: Box<Data<N>>) -> Box<DynData> {
        let ptr = Box::into_raw(data);
        let slice = std::ptr::slice_from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, 2*N) as _ ;
        // # SAFETY
        // - `Data` is `repr(C)` so field order and no-padding are known
        // - 2 arrays of length N combine into a single slice of 2*N
        // - alignment of `[f64; N]` and `[f64]` match
        // - trivially was allocated with the global allocator
        unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(slice)
        }
    }
}
impl<const N: usize> TryFrom<Box<DynData>> for Box<Data<N>> {
    type Error = Box<DynData>;
    fn try_from(dyn_data: Box<DynData>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if dyn_data.xy.len() != 2 * N {
            return Err(dyn_data);
        }

        let ptr = Box::into_raw(dyn_data) as *mut Data<N>;
        // # SAFETY
        // - `Data` is `repr(C)` so field order and no-padding are known
        // - a single slice of 2*N can be split into 2 arrays of length N
        // - alignment of `[f64; N]` and `[f64]` match
        // - trivially was allocated with the global allocator
        unsafe {
            Ok(Box::from_raw(ptr))
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Container {
    data: DynData,
}
```

Since DST aren't that well supported this requires a bit of `unsafe` though, so you might instead want to just use `Box<[f64]>` instead of the arrays directly:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Data {
    x: Box<[f64]>,
    y: Box<[f64]>,
}

impl Data {
    // you don't have to loose the static guarantee on creation either:
    fn new<const N: usize>(x: [f64; N], y: [f64; N]) -> Self {
        Data {
            x: x.into(),
            y: y.into(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid unsafe unless the performance are utmost important.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thats what I'm gonna do. Like suggested, I don't feel comfortable with the unsafe code, also because I don't fully understand what's going on, as I am not that comfortable with Rust yet.
A question about idiomaticness: I asked about how to do to get rid of generics. Is this even wise to do?